# Is it faster to wipe on delete than to wipe on create when maintaining data security?

Tags: security, delete-file, cloud-storage

Inspired by this question:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110734/why-didnt-oses-securely-delete-files-right-from-the-beginning-and-why-do-they

I'm proposing a multi-user scenario, especially where users are not to be trusted with each other's data, such as a cloud where disk space is reallocated, particularly to another user.

If the first user deletes a file, and the disk space is then reallocated to a second user, I presume that the physical area is wiped before handing it to the second user.  (Otherwise, we'd be inadvertently leaking information.)

**My question is, technically, is it faster to wipe:**

1. immediately after the delete
2. immediately before allocating it to the second user
3. by having a special "hook" that the program can flag the data as potentially sensitive
4. by running some garbage collection process in between
   (in which case, how do you cope with low disk space situations)

Also, I'm aware that this doesn't always happen in non-secure OSs.  **What's the term for ensuring that user's don't accidentally get allocated another user's unlinked data?**

Comment: What method of "wiping" are you performing? Just re-writing over that section of disk-space? (Some methods are optimized to either handle very small sectors of a disk, or for large overwrites of a large segment of files.) Number 3, would likely be the fastest as it would ignore wiping of non-secure files. However is every user of your system going to modify every program, kernel-mod, etc that they use to trigger the hook? (And even determine whether that specific program should trigger the hook.) While fast at runtime, would likely have to high of a barrier time (and thus money) cost to setup.

Comment: This is just my curiousity and theoretical.  I'd imagine there's real-world scenarios.  But, to answer your question, the wiping would be running zeros across the disk.  Yes, I believe some SSDs in particular have commands for blanking large sections of the storage area which may be an advantage.  In my scenario, the storage is entirely dumb, so a kernel write has the same impact as a db write.  Let's say that the processes could be VMs owned by different users so we can't differentiate between types of data being written or establish some data being more or less sensitive.

Comment: Hehe.  At some order of magnitude, if the volume of data is large enough, is it going to end up costing less time to physically destroy the device(s) and replace it with a new one? :-p

Comment: In the heavily theoretical scenario, I honestly can't say what the best option. Often times optimization really comes down to the very specific hardware, and system configurations. I would probably recommend setting up a test system (or systems) that you are interested in and performing a set of benchmark tests to determine which is the best option.